# view sql that linq-to-sql produces

Tags: linq-to-sql

Other than using profiler, is there a way to view the sql that linq-to-sql produces?

Answer (score 2):

I used LinqPad today to help debug a Linq2Sql issue.  It's a neat little tool, and will show you the SQL you're generating also.

http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Log property on the DataContext to write out what the SQL is.  This takes a TextWriter and is pretty easy to use.  If you need an example I can provide you one.

[DataContext Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your Linq-to-Sql query will be stored in a variable.  You can hover over this variable to inspect it and it will show you the generated SQL.

Another method is to output it using the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(dbContext.GetCommand(yourQuery).CommandText);
```

And of course Profiler which you already know about.

Comment: @meblah if this answer or another helped you, you should set an accepted answer so that others reading this question can locate the solution that helped you.