# Way to view SQL executed by LINQ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, linq-to-sql

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [view sql that linq-to-sql produces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235758/view-sql-that-linq-to-sql-produces)  *3 Answers*

I'm wondering if there is a way to see the T-SQL that was executed against the database in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate when a LINQ to SQL query runs.

Comment: Run SQL Sever profiler against that database and you can see what query is being executed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio Ultimate, you can see every SQL query your application runs in the IntelliTrace window while debugging.

Comment: Keep in mind that IntelliTrace is very resource-consuming. I usually have it disabled.

Comment: @Mr.TA: Isn't that only Calls View?

Comment: Maybe - I just disable the whole thing, makes me feel better. :)

Comment: Thanks!  I needed a quick easy way to view the SQL and this worked.

Comment: I do see queries in that window, but when I click to get more information I get a window that says `--The data may be truncated and may not represent the query that was run on the server`. The warning is correct, since the query in that window only has the name of the stored procedure and none of the information that I would find useful for debugging.

Comment: Its not available for Microsoft VS Professional 2015

Answer (score 11):

You can use SQL Server Profiler to do that.

Comment: That's one method, but not the only.

Comment: True, but then I doubt there is a single IT problem which has only one solution to it.

Comment: Then categorically stating that you `have` to do one particular thing is probably a bit off the mark ;)

Comment: @Dems changed "have to" to "can" - no arm twisting here :)

Answer (score 6):

You have basically two options:

1.) use a profiler, there's one free made by AnjLab http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler

2.) use LinqPad (again a free solution) http://www.linqpad.net/

You really don't need Ultimate VS or anything paid like some people already suggested...

Comment: AnjLab SQL profiler was bought out and is no longer free.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx) of the DataContext.

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
var custQuery =
    from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust;

foreach(Customer custObj in custQuery)
    Console.WriteLine(custObj.CustomerID);
```

Comment: Assuming the OP is using LINQ to SQL...

Comment: @jrummell: Quoting the OP, "when a LINQ query runs"

Comment: "LINQ query" is ambiguous. He could be using an NHibernate IQueryable adapter, but more likey LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework. Hopefully, the OP will clarify and we'll know for sure :)