# How convert linq query to SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I want convert following LINQ query to SQL query.

```
var ACTIVITY_ROYALITY_MONTH = from m in db.MiningPermit
                                      join pm in db.Permit_Mineral on m.MINING_PERMIT_ID equals pm.MINING_PERMIT_ID
                                      join r in db.Royality on pm.Permit_Minerals_ID equals r.Permit_Minerals_ID
                                      where r.ORDER_ID == 0 // NULL in server
                                      orderby r.YEAR, r.MONTH
                                      group r by new { m.MINING_PERMIT_ID , r.YEAR, r.MONTH }  into mpmr
                                      select mpmr.ToList();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can view actual query that is being executed. See this to find out how to view SQL query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002573/way-to-view-sql-executed-by-linq-in-visual-studio

Comment: That's a bad LINQ query - LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL and the JOINs are generated by EF or L2S based on the context relations. What it does isn't what it looks like either - there's no way you can use `GROUP BY` and get *any* non-group column back without aggregation. What this really does is join some tables and return all rows and columns. You can copy it as-is, put `SELECT *` at the top and remove the `GROUP BY` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Linqpad](https://www.linqpad.net/) and recreate the linq (even by bringing in your assemblies) in a C# query. Run the query. Then in the output, there is a selection button of `SQL` which will show the sql code.